# change the UICollectionViewcell content from imageTap Gesture Recognition selector method with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode7, uicollectionviewcell

I have one CollectionViewcell and i set tapGestureRecognizer action to my thumbnail image on the bottom page ( the small image ). I want the method to change my big image with the small one, but how to access the content of my cell ? I have tried this, i got the imageURL and i got the indexPath but i failed to change the content of my cell

[Sample Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Dne.png)

```
 func tapThumbnail(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let thumbnail = sender.view as! UIImageView
    let url = thumbnail.sd_imageURL() as! NSURL

    let point = sender.locationInView(self.collectionView)
    let indexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)


    let cell = self.collectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(productsIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! ProductsSpotlightViewCell
    cell.productImage.sd_setImageWithURL(url)
}
```

any 1 have simple solution ?

Comment: whenever u tap on it just set FLAG value and then reload collectionview and in cellForRow method , chck this flag value and if it satisfy your condition then change image else let it be same , hope u got my point !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out!

change my cell declaration to this

```
 let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```